# Consolidate MySQL Query Result Into Single Record

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to find a way to structure a SQL Query. The data I need is in two table and comprises of 3 records, but I need to return this in a way so that I can later insert it into a table as 1 record. The query will be used within PHP so I am open to using this as well. Here is what I have:

```
SELECT ID, meta_key, meta_value
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
    ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE post_status = 'publish'
AND post_date >= CURDATE()
AND post_type IN ('tribe_events', 'tribe_organizer', 'tribe_venue')
AND meta_key IN ('_EventStartDate', '_EventEndDate', '_OrganizerOrganizer', '_OrganizerWebsite', '_VenueAddress', '_VenueCity', '_VenueState', '_VenueZip')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try self-joins with individual matches, i.e. instead of using

```
 WHERE post_type IN (val1, val2, val3)
```

do the following

```
 INNER JOIN
       ... ON table2.post_type = val2
 INNER JOIN
       ... ON table3.post_type = val3
 etc.
 WHERE table1.post_type = val1
```

or whatever works. You get the idea. I don't know your schema and can't give you a more specific example.